# Trouble deploying my node app into Hostinger, centOS > CyberPanel when it works fine at localhost:3030

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, sendgrid

I am a little unsure how to configure this code so it can work proparly as I deploy it into Hostinger > centOS > CyberPanel!

I know I have to point my IP/domain elsewhere to get it to connect with my front-end project!

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const sendGrid = require('@sendGrid/mail');


const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.get('/api', (req, res, next ) => {
    res.send('API Status: Running!')
});


app.post('/api/email',(req, res, next) =>{
    //SendGrid API KEY
    sendGrid.setApiKey('My Api Key');

    console.log(req.body)

    const msg = {
        to: 'My Email',
        from: 'Authenticated Email',
        subject: 'Herms Portfolio',
        text: req.body.message,
        html: req.body.email
        
        
        
    }

    sendGrid.send(msg)
    .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.body);
        res.status(401).json({
            success: false
            
        })
        
    });


});

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: what errors do you get? what options have you tried?

Comment: hey @Re9iNee. I have installed nodeJS on my server and set up my context to what it should be ( i think ) inside vHOST. what i do not understand is how my code should look like when its ready to be deployed! ( i mean, can i basicaly just copy the code? and paste it into my cPanel, or in my case cyberPanel) How can i get my app.js ( Node app ) to  cooperate with my front end code. This is a sendMail attempt app.

Comment: @Krutz did you install NPM and the packages that you used in the code above? (edit this post and add package.json file).

Comment: Yes. Dependencies = "@sendGrid/mail", "body-parser", "cors", "express", "nodemon"

Comment: I've Never Worked with CyberPanel, use express.static to server HTML files and make a directory to serve Your (Front-End) Files. let me know if you want more details